# Massive problem with splitting data from JSON file in R

Tags: r, json, datetime, split

I'm new to R and I'm having problems splitting my data that I imported locally which is JSON file containing SensorID, TimeStamp, SensorValue and SensorUnits. But it is not showing me any results. Whereas the same JSON file called through a web link works completely fine.

Help please!

Here is the JSON file as a text:

```
[
    {
    "paramname": "coltimestamp",
        "paramvalue": "TIMESTAMP"
    },
    {
    "paramname": "colsensorid",
        "paramvalue": "SENSORID"
    },
    {
    "paramname": "colsensorvalue",
        "paramvalue": "SENSORVALUE"
    },
    {
    "paramname": "sensorid",
        "paramvalue": "D1"
    },
    {
    "paramname": "datatimeformat",
        "paramvalue": "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"
    },
    {
    "paramname": "intimezone",
        "paramvalue": "GMT"
    },
    {
    "paramname": "rangetimeformat",
        "paramvalue": "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"
    },
    {
    "paramname": "Pfrom",
        "paramvalue": "20160324 00:00:00"
    },
    {
    "paramname": "Pto",
        "paramvalue": "20160325 00:00:00"
    },
    {
    "paramname": "Cfrom",
        "paramvalue": "20160325 00:00:00"
    },
    {
    "paramname": "Cto",
        "paramvalue": "20160326 00:00:00"
    },
    {
    "paramname": "thresholdpercent",
        "paramvalue": 25
    }
]
```

Here is the part of the code that I am having problems with:

Function to split data into 2 datasets: Previous, Current

```
IN: Standard Data Frame, SensorID,   
    Previous From Time stamp, Previous To Time stamp,   
    Current From Time Stamp, Current To Time Stamp  
OUT: Data series     
     series 1 (SensorID, TimeStamp, SensorValue),  
     series 2 (SensorID, TimeStamp, SensorValue) 


    f_splitdataseries <- function(SensorID, Intimeformat, Datatimeformat, PFrom, PTo, CFrom, CTo)
    {
      PFromPOSIX = as.POSIXct(PFrom, format=Intimeformat, tz="GMT", usetz=FALSE);
      PToPOSIX = as.POSIXct(PTo, format=Intimeformat, tz="GMT", usetz=FALSE);
      CFromPOSIX = as.POSIXct(CFrom, format=Intimeformat, tz="GMT", usetz=FALSE);
      CToPOSIX = as.POSIXct(CTo, format=Intimeformat, tz="GMT", usetz=FALSE);

      mydata$TimeStampPOSIX <- as.POSIXct(mydata$TimeStamp, 
                                           format=Datatimeformat, tz="GMT", usetz=FALSE);

      series1 = mydata[which(mydata$SensorID ==SensorID & 
                                mydata$TimeStampPOSIX >= PFromPOSIX & mydata$TimeStampPOSIX < PToPOSIX),];
      series2 = mydata[which(mydata$SensorID ==SensorID & 
                                mydata$TimeStampPOSIX >= CFromPOSIX & mydata$TimeStampPOSIX < CToPOSIX),];
      return(list(series1, series2));
    }

    Running the above function, splitting data into 2
    s = f_splitdataseries (SensorID=v_sensorid,
                           Intimeformat=v_rangetimeformat, Datatimeformat=v_datatimeformat,
                           PFrom=v_Pfrom, PTo=v_Pto,
                           CFrom=v_Cfrom, CTo=v_Cto)

    Unpack the 2 list of data frames
    series1 <- s[[1]]
    series2 <- s[[2]]
```

Comment: Hi Ismail. What you have showed are not snippets of json, they are screenshots of imported data in a rectangular format. No-one can test your code with these. Please either include the original json as text or a `dput` of the resulting data frame

Comment: Hi @AllanCameron! Thanks for getting back so quickly, I'll add in the code down here. If you need the source data file do let me know as well.